# Creating a personalized stylesheet for xml files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml files which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="jats-html.xsl"?>
<article article-type="proceedings">
    <front>
        <journal-meta>
            <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id"/>
        </journal-meta>
        <article-meta>
            <article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1117/12.2049309</article-id>
            <title-group>
                <article-title>POLARIZATION-INDUCED ANGULAR MOMENTUM OF ARBITRARY LIGHT-SCATTERING PARTICLE</article-title>
            </title-group>
            <contrib-group>
                <contrib contrib-type="author">
                    <name>
                        <surname>Sakhnovskii</surname>
                        <given-names>M.Yu.</given-names>
                    </name>
                </contrib>
                <contrib contrib-type="author">
                    <name>
                        <surname>Rudeychuk</surname>
                        <given-names>V.M.</given-names>
                    </name>
                </contrib>
                <contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="yes">
                    <name>
                        <surname>Polyanskii</surname>
                        <given-names>P.V.</given-names>
                    </name>
                </contrib>
            </contrib-group>
        </article-meta>
    </front>
</article>
```

I want to see the given names and surnames in a table format. I'm new to XSLT and below is the stylesheet that I've made, but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sample</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Surname</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="article/front/article-meta/contrib-group/contrib">
                        <tr bgcolor="red">
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="given-names"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="surname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in xsl file?
Expected output looks something like this [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9xYc.png)

The actual outout I'm getting is
[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TUHD.png)

Comment: What is the expected output, the actual output, and the problem?  _"It doesn't work"_ is insufficient.

Comment: The expected output is a table which shows Given-name and Surname in the table head and the respective values of Given-name and Surname in the table body, but the actual output just shows the table head and the body portion is empty.

Comment: [edit] your post and show the expected and actual output.

Comment: @JimGarrison We ask posters to provide a *reproducible* example, which OP did. Running it provides all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what is wrong in xsl file?

You are missing a location step in your selection. Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="article/front/article-meta/contrib-group/contrib">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="article/front/article-meta/contrib-group/contrib/name">
```